# To me vs for me

Tags: prepositions

What's the correct sentence: `You might be able to find a job for me` or `You might be able to find a job to me`? I never understand the rules of for vs to and I just use them interchangeably. Is there a rule to follow?

Comment: Actually, prepositions are hard, and different languages have different ideas about what is right. Visiting Paris once, I learned I was staying *in France* but *inside Paris*. Who knew? Makes sense, but English might use *in* for both.

Comment: You are findng on behalf of someone so it is ***for*** them.

Comment: Hello, mrEmpanada, welcome to ELU! In this case, you should say: "You might be able to find a job **for** me". In many cases they are not interchangeable, but the change often is still easily understandable. Cheers!  ([Here is a related question that may be helpful](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74005/grammar-for-vs-to))

Comment: Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 1):

I think the "for" that means you need a job ,and the "to" means you can provide jobs.

Comment: Maybe you mean you can send such jobs *to me*, or I can provide them *to you*?

Comment: yes, it's my means, thank you for your explanation